# how to include json-ld script in nuxt 3?

Tags: json, vue.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to add json-ld to my page, but still not working or not what I want.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. using useMeta()

```
useMeta({
    script: [
        {
            type: 'application/ld-json',
            json: jsonLd,
        },
    ],
});
```

result: `<script type="application/ld-json" json="[object Object]"></script>`

2. using `<Script>` tag

```
<Script type="application/ld-json">
        {{ jsonLd }}
</Script>
```

result: `<script type="application/ld+json"></script>` empty value.

and

```
<Script type="application/ld-json" v-html="jsonLd"></Script>
```

result: `<script type="application/ld-json" innerhtml="[object Object]"></script>`

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If in case anyone wondering, this is how I get it to work:

Using

`<Script :children="jsonLd" />`

Or

```
useMeta({
    script: [
        {
            type: 'application/ld-json',
            children: JSON.stringify(jsonLd),
        },
    ],
});
```

Comment: Where did you add this into? Directly into nuxt 3 nuxt config.ts? I tried to use it but `useMeta` is not recognized as a function.

Comment: Add it into your component or page in nuxt 3.

Comment: This is more or less the [implementation in nuxt-jsonld](https://github.com/ymmooot/nuxt-jsonld/blob/master/packages/nuxt-jsonld/src/runtime/composable.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Nuxt 3 support will be added soon: https://github.com/ymmooot/nuxt-jsonld/issues/763

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nuxt-jsonld](https://github.com/ymmooot/nuxt-jsonld), a Nuxt 3 module to manage JSON-LD

Answer (score 0):

it's worked for me in nuxt 3:

```
useHead({
script: [{
    type: 'application/ld+json',
    innerHTML: JSON.stringify({
        "type": "application/ld+json",
        "textContent": {
            "@context": "https://schema.org",
            "@type": "Article",
            "headline": "",
            "image": [
                ""
            ],
            "author": [{
                "@type": "Person",
                "name": "",
                "url": ""
            }]
        }
    })
}],
__dangerouslyDisableSanitizers: ['script'],
})
```